# How does the compiler infer types in this Box::leak(node).into()?

Tags: rust, type-inference

I'm trying to understand [`linked_list.rs`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/library/alloc/src/collections/linked_list.rs) and I came across this line in the `push_back_node` function where `node` is a `Box`:

```
let node = Some(Box::leak(node).into());
```

This somehow produces an `Option<NonNull<Node>>>` even though no types were specified. What's going on here and why does it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost all of the types are determined just by the functions being called. The only tricky one is the `into` call.

If `t` has type `T`, then `Some(t)` is of type `Option<T>`. If `bx` has type `Box<T>`, then `Box::leak(bx)` has type `&mut T`. `into` uses whatever information available (within reason) to determine the input type and the expected output type and uses the `Into` trait to determine if a conversion is possible.

So since `node` (before this rebinding) has type `Box<Node<T>>`, `Box::leak(node)` has type `&mut Node<T>`. The `into` converts to some type `U` to be determined, and the `Some` wraps in an option as type `Option<U>`.

However, that's not all we know. Later on in `push_back_node`, we have the line `self.head = node`. That constrains the type of the new `node` (which we said was `Option<U>` for some type `U`) to be the same as `self.head`. `self.head` is known to have type `Option<NonNull<Node<T>>>`, so `U` must be `NonNull<Node<T>>`.

So the `into` call has to convert from `&mut Node<T>` to `NonNull<Node<T>>`. Check if there's an implementation of `Into<NonNull<Node<T>>>` for `&mut Node<T>`...and there is! If `U` implements `From<T>` then `T` automatically (via a blanket `impl`) implements `Into<U>`, and there's [an implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html#impl-From%3C%26%27_%20mut%20T%3E) of `From<&mut T>` for `NonNull<T>`!

---

For more (and a more precise overview of how the compiler thinks about this), check out [the chapter on type inference](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/type-inference.html) and the next chapter on trait solving in the `rustc` dev guide.